# In Identity for Entity Framework Core 3.x, how do I find users by Email (minding normalization) when Email uniqueness is not enforced?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-3.1

`userManager.FindByEmailAsync(myEmail)` throws an exception if there are multiple users with the same email.

I could use:

```
await context.ApplicationUsers
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == myEmail.ToUpperInvariant());
```

That seems to work okay. But I'm not sure if ToUpperInvariant is the right way to check, because System.Text also has Normalize(). It won't matter right now since we are using SQL Server with a case-insensitive configuration, but I don't want things to break if we ever change that.

Am I normalizing in a way that is consistent with how Entity Framework does it? I tried to find the source code, but [what I found](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/a24b776676f12cf7f0e13944783cf8e379b3ef70/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs) doesn't use the NormalizedEmail field, so it's likely old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normalization is not done by the EF Core, but the `UserManager` class (using [ILookupNormalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ilookupnormalizer?view=aspnetcore-3.1) service injected via constructor or set via [KeyNormalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.keynormalizer?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property).

`UserManager.FindByEmailAsync` method [does the normalization for you](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1426) before calling the store method. The problem is that EF Core store method implementation [uses SingleOrDefaultAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L640) which throws if there are duplicate normalized emails in the database.

To fix that, you could use [UserManager.NormalizeEmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.normalizeemail?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method to do the normalization, and then use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` query as in your sample:

```
var normalizedEmail = userManager.NormalizeEmail(myEmail);
var firstDuplicate = await userManager.Users
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == normalizedEmail);
```

Comment: I believe so. And here is [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer.cs).

Comment: I deleted the comment you replied to where I asked if `UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer` was likely the implementation I was getting. `ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILookupNormalizer>()` is indeed an `UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer` in my app.

Comment: FWIW, it's registered for DI [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L43).